# Java lock type that cancel execution if another thread is doing it

Tags: java, android, multithreading, concurrency

The only tool I know for java concurrency is synchronized, which is, if 2 threads calling the same method, one will wait for another to finish before executing.

However, for my use case, I would like the 2nd thread to drop the call, if another thread is executing the code. Something like:

```
boolean isInUse = false;

public void doWorkIfNotBusy() {
  if (isInUse) {
    return;
  } else {
    isInUse = true;
    // do work
    isInUse = false;
  }
}
```

The code has bug. There must be a simple yet correct way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not correct because a non-volatile variable is accessed from multiple threads without any additional synchronization(see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4 for details of Java memory model). You can use `Lock` and its `tryLock` method to achieve the desired behavior:

```
Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();

public void doWorkIfNotBusy() {
    if (lock.tryLock()) {
        try {
            // do work
         } finally {
             lock.unlock();
         }
     } 
}
```

If the lock is successfully acquired, it does the work and then releases the lock. Otherwise, it returns immediately. You can read more about it here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html.